# Structure of certain "arithmetic" sets

Tags: co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

First, define an *arithmetic* set as a finite subset $A$ of the segment $[-1,1]$ which satisfies the following conditions:

1. $\{-1,1\}\subset A$.
2. For each $a\in A\setminus\{\pm 1\}$ there are two distinct elements $b,c\in A$ such that $2a=b+c$.

For our problem we also add the "symmetry condition", i. e. we require

3. $A=-A$.

**Question.** Is it possible to describe all such arithmetic sets? For example, is it true that $A$ is an union of arithmetic progressions containing $\pm 1$?

It can be shown that all elements of $A$ are rational numbers (it's a nice linear algebra exercise).

Any help (e. g. references) would be appreciated.

Comment: Classification looks pretty hopeless; there are many examples.  For instance, take $A$ to be a symmetric set of multiples of $1/N$ in $[-1,1]$ that contains all the multiples of $1/N$ in $[-1,-1/3] \cup [1/3,1]$ but only an arbitrary subset of those multiples in $(-1/3,1/3)$, for any given $N$.  Or a finite union of such sets for various values of $N$.